# Объясните пожалуйста программу и ее работу

Tags: python

```
import random
randomList = [random.randint(-100,100) for i in range(10)]
print(randomList)
maxrandomList = max(randomList) 
for i in randomList[:]: 
    if i == maxrandomList:
        randomList.remove(i)
print(max(randomList))
```

Comment: создаём список случайных числе. находим максимальный среди них. удаляем все элементы равные максимальному. находим максимальный их оставшихся элементом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Подробное объяснение

Смотрите `import random` подключает библиотеку random
`randomList = [random.randint(-100,100) for i in range(10)]`
Генерирует список из 10 чисел которые будут подобраны случайным образом от -100 до 100
`maxrandomList = max(randomList)` переменной `maxrandomList` присваивается элемент списка с **самым** большим числом

```py
for i in randomList[:]: 
    if i == maxrandomList:
        randomList.remove(i)
print(max(randomList))
```

Ищет элемент в списке схожий с `maxrandomList` и при его нахождение удаляет этот элемент.
После этого выводит новый элемент списка с **самым** большим числом

Comment: Понятно объяснил?